# Subtract 2 rows using case statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My data is like below, it's in a single table

```
Column1   Column2
abc       100
abc       200
```

Now I need like below

```
abc 100 //here 200-100
```

I am banging my head on how to achieve this.

I have tried to use the row_number and then subtract using case statement like

```
Select
  column1,
  sum(
    case when rownum=1
    then column2
    end
    -
    case when rownum=2
    then column2
    end
  )
from table
group by column1
```

But this is giving me null.

Comment: what if there are more rows? how do you specify the order of rows?

Comment: @RadimBača no only 2 rows at any time

Comment: `SUM(CASE rownum WHEN 2 THEN -Column2 ELSE Column2 END)`. Subtraction is just inverse addition.

Comment: You need an attribute specifying the order of your rows (which one is the first and which is the second).

Comment: @RadimBača yes for that reason I took row_number I am able to get row numbers but unable to subtract row 1 to row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an attribute `rownum` in `table` which is always 1 or 2 (it can be generated by some row_number() as you suggest in question, according to any order that is suitable for you)

```
Column1   Column2  Rownum
------------------------ 
abc       100      1
abc       200      2
```

then you can simply use

```
Select
    column1,
    sum(
        case when rownum=1
        then column2
        else -column2
        end
    )
from table
group by column1
```

It performs a sum of the `Column2` per `Column1`, however, in the row having `rownum = 2` the `Column2` value is negated. Therefore in our example you end up with 100 + (-200) = -100

Comment: Baca.. awsome sir... perfectly worked.. can you please help to explain logic

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no attribute which can define row ordering -

```
;with cte as(
    select
        row_number() over (order by (select null)) as IndexId,
        Column1,
        Column2
    from @xyz
)
select sum(case when IndexID=1 then (-1 * Column2) else Column2 end), Column1
from cte
group by Column1
```

Input data-

```
declare @xyz table(Column1   varchar(10),Column2 int)
insert into @xyz
select 'abc'       ,100 union all
select 'abc'       ,200
```

Comment: thanks for answer but Radim solution has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
select column1, max(column2) - min(column2)
from t
group by column1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.. But I need to subtract row1 - row2 not max from min.. is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short form of the answer above if you care:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    SUM(IIF(rownum=1,column2,-column2))
FROM table
GROUP BY column1
```